# Get all data from DB using fetchall_hashref

Tags: perl, cgi, dbi, hashref

I am using fetchall_hashref to get data satisfying a condition from a mysql DB.The data retrieved will be stored in a hash and then be used futhur by a javascript function.

I want to retrieve all the rows of 3 columns and store it in a hash but not being able to do that.

The table structure..

[table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QRn4.png)
[image: table structure]

the table data..

[table data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oba8f.png)
[image: table data]

the code being used..

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
#print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
use DBI;
use CGI;
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;
use Data::Dumper;

use CGI::Carp qw (fatalsToBrowser);
my $q = CGI->new;
print  $q->header;
my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:Demo:localhost";   # Data source name
my $username = "mint";                 # User name
my $password = "MINT123";              # Password
my $dbh;
my $sth;    
my $b;
my $c;  
        # Database and statement handles
 $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $username, $password);


 my $hash = $dbh->selectall_hashref("SELECT `desc`,date1,riskval from FIR2 where date1 between date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 1 WEEK) and now() order by date1", 'riskval');
 print Dumper($hash);
 $b=join(",",$hash);
 delete $_->{riskval} for values %$hash;

 $dbh->disconnect();
```

The output i am getting in browser...

[image: browser output]

the output in putty..

[image]

As you can see I want to print the row where "riskval" is null,the value of "riskval" is 5 in 2 places but only 1 row is getting printed..

after i replaced selectall_hashref with selectall_arrayref i got the following error message in putty..

[image: second error message]

Please help..

Comment: hash can't have multiple identical keys so you'll have to change approach by using hash of arrays or something similar.

Comment: can you give an example???

Comment: sure, http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#Declaration-of-a-HASH-OF-ARRAYS

Comment: i mean an example similar to mine where they values are being retrieved from a mysql DB and stored in hash of arrays..

Answer (score 4):

> i mean an example similar to mine where they values are being
>   retrieved from a mysql DB and stored in hash of arrays

According to [the DBI documentation](https://metacpan.org/module/TIMB/DBI-1.627/DBI.pm),

> If $slice is a hash reference, `fetchall_arrayref` fetches each row as a
>   hash reference...
>
> For example, to fetch all fields of every row as a hash ref:
>
> `$tbl_ary_ref = $sth->fetchall_arrayref({});`

Replace your `fetchall_hashref` with that and you should get all records as an array of hashes, including those with duplicate `riskval`s.

**Edit:** I missed that OP is using `selectall_*` rather than `fetchall_*`.  In that case, the relevant section of the DBI documentation is:

> You may often want to fetch an array of rows where each row is stored
>   as a hash. That can be done simple using:
>
> ```
> my $emps = $dbh->selectall_arrayref(
>     "SELECT ename FROM emp ORDER BY ename",
>     { Slice => {} }
> );
> ```

Comment: i replaced "fetchall_hashref" with "fetchall_arrayref" and got the error message in putty as posted above in the second picture...

Comment: Again, look at the documentation. Their example for using `selectall_arrayref` to get an array of hashes is: `my $emps = $dbh->selectall_arrayref(
    "SELECT ename FROM emp ORDER BY ename",
    { Slice => {} }
);` Note that the only parameters are the query and `{ Slice => {} }`.